# SQL: посчитать количество пар

Tags: sql

Друзья, такой вопрос. Есть таблица, содержащая значения покупатель-товар, вида:

```
| Ваня | Товар 1 |
| Ваня | Товар 2 |
| Петя | Товар 1 |
| Петя | Товар 2 |
| Петя | Товар 3 |
```

Нужно сделать запрос, считающий для каждой пары товаров, количество покупателей, их купивших т.е.:

```
Товар 1, Товар 2 - 2
Товар 1, Товар 3 - 1
Товар 2, Товар 3 - 1
```

Ума не приложу, как это сделать. Подскажите, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: поясните почему пример именно 2 и 1.

Comment: Заметил ошибку в примере, поправил

Answer (score 2):

О, кажется все же нашел ответ!

Для оптимизации вычислений нужен индекс:

```
create index itemslog_userid_itemname on itemslog(userid, itemname);
```

И затем можно использовать обычный запрос через JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.itemname, t2.itemname, count(*),  
 FROM itemslog AS t1 
 JOIN itemslog AS t2
 ON t1.userid = t2.userid AND t1.itemname < t2.itemname
 GROUP BY t1.itemname, t2.itemname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант сделать что-то в духе

```
Select t1.name, t2.name, count(*) as count  from order as t1, order  as t2 where t1.name < t2.name and t1.user = t2.user group by t1.name, t2.name;
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, способ вполне рабочий. Но... только на маленьких выборках. Может есть идеи, как это заставить работать на больших массивах (более 200к записей)?

Comment: @lonely_luckily а есть ещё ограничения? в лоб тут размер ответа порядка квадрата от размера. 200,000 в квадрате это миллиарды строк в ответе.

Comment: за исключением объема, других ограничений нет

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Такой вариант вполне работоспособен, если использовать индекс (я написал ответ ниже)